# jQuery fadeIn not working in Firefox Mozilla 33.0.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have very strange problem.

I have a line of code which is working okey in Chrome, Opera and IE.

Here is the whole Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){     
        $("#SuperWebF1").click(function(){
        if ($('[name="shipping_method"]', window.parent.document).is(':checked')){
        billing.save();     
        $("#LoadingDiv", window.parent.document).show().delay(4300).fadeOut();
        $("#OutDiv", window.parent.document).hide().delay(5000).fadeIn();
        $('#OutDiv', window.parent.document).removeClass('outerdiv');
        $('#OutDiv', window.parent.document).removeClass('outerdivNoAdress');
        $('#OutDiv', window.parent.document).addClass('OuterDiv1000');

        $('#InnerIframe', window.parent.document).removeClass('FrameCSS');
        $('#InnerIframe', window.parent.document).removeClass('FrameCSSNoAdress');
        $('#InnerIframe', window.parent.document).addClass('FrameCSS1000');
    }else {
    alert('Моля, изберете начин на доставка!');
    }   

        })
    });
    </script>
```

The problem is in the following line:

`$("#OutDiv", window.parent.document).hide().delay(5000).fadeIn();`

Here just the `fadeIn()` function is not working only in Firefox.

Where can be the problem guys and how i can fix it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tested your code on firefox 33 without problem.

Answer (score -1):

The jquery does not take asp.net imagebutton correctly on firefox. Once it is changed to html link image control, jquery effect works.